# tar extract with user ignores umask on CentOS 8

Tags: tar, umask

Usually as far as I know when extracting files with tar the users umask should be used for new permissions.
My umask is 0007. So when I create new files they have the permission: -rw-rw----

I have a tar file that contains files with these permissions:
-rw-r--r--

When I extract the tar file using `tar -xzf file.tar.gz` the files change their permissioning to
-rw-r-----

So the permissions change but the groups write permission is missing.

Am I missing something?

Answer (score 1):

The umask doesn't outright replace the permissions, it is *applied to* the base permissions that the program specifies when trying to create a file. Its purpose is only to remove permission bits, that's why it's called a "mask".

For example, when you use `touch`, it asks the OS to create a file with permissions 0666 and after applying the umask to it you get `0666 & ~0007 = 0660`.

However, when tar is extracting your file which was 0644, the umask is *applied to that 0644* so the final result is of course `0644 & ~0007 = 0640`.

In short, the umask can only make permissions more restrictive, not less. (Similarly, when e.g. ssh-keygen wants to create a 0600 file to hold your private key, it will still remain 0600 even after the umask has been applied – it will never become 0644 nor 0660 nor something else.)

Comment: So there is no way to accomplish this without manually changing permissions afterwards?